# list records from sql server UDF that returns Table in classic asp

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, ado, user-defined-functions

I wrote my first sql Server returning table UDF since thought was better than using a SP
but, while can easily retrieve the result from sql server.. I can't get result calling it from classic ASP ADO

UDF is as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_Alert 
(
  @I nvarchar (30),
  @L nvarchar (10)
)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN 
(
  SELECT a.Message, a.Height, a.backgroundColor, a.isFree
    from Advice a 
    join ActiveMessages b on b.MessageID=a.MessageID
    join Items i on b.ItemID=i.ItemID
    join Sellers s on i.UserID=s.UserID
    join Users u on u.UID=s.UID
  WHERE 
    (i.ItemID=@I and a.Active='1' and b.Active='1' and i.active='1' and i.Show='1' and CHARINDEX('ALERT',u.Modules)>0
    and a.ValidFrom<GETDATE() and a.ValidTo>GETDATE() and u.PaidUntil>GETDATE() and charindex(@L,a.Languages)>-1 or charindex('all',a.Languages)>-1 )
UNION ALL
  SELECT a.Message, a.Height, a.backgroundColor, a.isFree
  FROM Advice a, Users u
  WHERE      u.isFree='1' and a.isFree='1' and (CHARINDEX(@L,a.Languages)>-1 or Charindex('all',a.Languages)>-1)
)
```

and I can easily execute from SSMS calling

```
Select * from dbo.udf_Alert('281F50246','fr')
```

But I have to embed into a classic ASP routine but I've not found the way to do it..

tried the SP method.. but I got error when try to set the parameters:
here what I tried:

```
sql="Select dbo.udf_Alert('xx','yy')"   
dim cmdA
set cmdA = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmdA.ActiveConnection= cn
cmdA.CommandType=4
cmdA.CommandText=sql
cmda.Parameters.Append cmdA.CreateParameter("fd", nvarchar, adParamInput,30, itemID)
cmda.Parameters.Append cmdA.CreateParameter("fde", nvarchar, adParamInput,10, LanguageID)
'   cmdA.Parameters("@I")=ItemID     '<-----ERRROR HERE
'   cmdA.Parameters("@L")=LanguageID
set rs=cmdA.Execute()
```

so I tried set Parametrs in other way.. but got same result:

```
ADODB.Command error '800a0bb9'
Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.
```

Can suggest some advice?

Thanks
Sergio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We tend to create stored procedure "wrappers" for UDFs on a one-to-one basis which can be called directly from web code.  For your example, this might look like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[pr_Alert] 
  @I nvarchar (30),
  @L nvarchar (10)
AS

SELECT * FROM testDb.dbo.udf_Alert(@I, @L)

RETURN
```

Your commandText would then be simply the name of the wrapper SP, "pr_Alert".

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi!
Thanks.. works well.. but.. then could be simpler to write directly a SP with Table Output... or still better write UDF + SP?
Thanks again.